# How can I set the Dragging Image in SwiftUI on macOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I am trying to change the preview image for drag and drop from the default for a GridView which seems to include all the visible items in the grid.

As I understand it I should be able to set the `NSItemProvider.previewImageHandler` block to customize the image that gets used.

I can't seem to find any examples of what such a block would look like in order to return a custom image.  Can anyone provide an example of such a block returning an Image.

In addition is it also necessary to call the loadPreviewImage() method on the NSItemProvider - I assume not and that macOS will do this.

Here is what I have so far but this previewHandler is not getting called.

```
.onDrag {
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: fileService )
    itemProvider.previewImageHandler = {completion, expectedClass, options in
        os_log("previewImageHandler called")
        let image = NSImage(named: "film")
        if let data = image?.tiffRepresentation {
            completion?(data as NSSecureCoding, nil)
        } else {
            let error = NSError(domain:"", code:001, userInfo:[ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to create preview image"])
            completion?(nil, error)
        }
    }
    return itemProvider
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS 12 and iOS 15, the `onDrag` modifier has an initialiser with a `preview` that accepts a `ViewBuilder` closure to provide a preview image.

Here is an example.

```
.onDrag({
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: fileService )
    itemProvider.previewImageHandler = {completion, expectedClass, options in
        os_log("previewImageHandler called")
        let image = NSImage(named: "film")
        if let data = image?.tiffRepresentation {
            completion?(data as NSSecureCoding, nil)
        } else {
            let error = NSError(domain:"", code:001, userInfo:[ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to create preview image"])
            completion?(nil, error)
        }
    }
    return itemProvider

}, preview: {
    Image("myImage")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
        .foregroundColor(.teal)
        .padding()
})
```

Comment: Note that this initializer is only available in macOS 12 and iOS 15 or above. Here's the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/ondrag(_:preview:)

Comment: @alobaili Good point, I’ll update the answer. Thanks

Comment: is it me or the new `preview` is buggy? when my View is redrawn, the preview is not getting updated and keeps showing the image of the first drag i did.