# How do I modify the background color and shape of drag&drop preview SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-scrollview

I'm trying to implement simple list with draggable cells (iOS 15). For now I have two base solutions: List and ScrollView. None of this methods doesn't lead me to appropriate result.

First of all I'll provide some code:

### List item view:

```swift
struct ListItemView: View {
    let index: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Item \(index)")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.gray)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16.0))
    }
}
```

### First solution (using List):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< 10) { i in
            ListItemView(index: i)
                .onDrag {
                    NSItemProvider(object: String(describing: "item_\(i)") as NSString)
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 8.0)
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 0, trailing: 8))
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
    }
}
```

The result is fine, but when I start dragging action, I see some white rect around my cell, which is not what I want:

[image: Drag&Drop preview using ScrollView]

### Second solution (using ScrollView)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(0 ..< 10) { i in
                ListItemView(index: i)
                    .onDrag {
                        NSItemProvider(object: String(describing: "item_\(i)") as NSString)
                    }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.black)
    }
}
```

The result is a bit different: we don't see any coloured rects (I suppose, this is because we are not using List and there is different mechanism of drag&drop feature). Also there is scaled preview and shape without rounded corners.

[image: Drag&Drop preview using List]

So, the desirable behaviour is:
a) the size of preview is the same as original size of list item
b) there is rounded-corners shape without white frame

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically your `NSItemProvider` can offer a `previewImageHandler` which is a block that draws the image you want the system to use as the drag preview.  Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.  The documentation of the `onDrag` modifier says that it uses a picture of the view as the preview image and it seemingly ignores the `previewImageHandler`. If someone finds out otherwise, leave a comment and I'll amend the answer.  Here's what I tried:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListItem : Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
}

let itemsInList = (0..<10).map { ListItem(id: $0, title: "Item \($0)") }

@ViewBuilder func ListItemView(title : String) -> some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18, style: .circular)
            .foregroundColor(Color(red: 142.0/255.0, green: 142.0/255.0, blue: 142.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0))
        Text(title)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(itemsInList) {
            let itemTitle = $0.title
            ListItemView(title: itemTitle)
                .onDrag {
                    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider()
                    itemProvider.registerObject("Item \(itemTitle)" as NSString, visibility: .all)
                    itemProvider.previewImageHandler = {
                        (completionHandler, expectedClass, options) -> Void in

                        var resultImage : CGImage?

                        debugPrint(expectedClass ?? "Unknown")
                        if let cgContext = CGContext(data: nil,
                                                     width: 72,
                                                     height: 72,
                                                     bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                                     bytesPerRow: 16 * (((72 * 4) + 15) / 16),
                                                     space: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!,
                                                     bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue) {

                            let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 72, height: 72)
                            cgContext.clear(frame)
                            cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
                            cgContext.fillEllipse(in: frame)

                            resultImage = cgContext.makeImage()
                        }

                        if let completionHandler = completionHandler {
                            if let resultImage = resultImage {
                                completionHandler(UIImage(cgImage: resultImage), nil)
                            } else {
                                completionHandler(nil, NSError(domain: "ItemCompletion", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return itemProvider
                }
        }
    }
}


struct previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, Scott, thank you for your answer! I tried to implement this handler for my `NSItemProvider`, but it isn't being called (I suppose, iOS should manage this by itself). The only way I get this – calling `loadPreviewImage` method by myself.
Could you please provide some more details about how to use this handler?

P.S. I found similar question about `previewImageHandler`, but sadly, there are no any answer or example at all... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67248900/how-can-i-set-the-dragging-image-in-swiftui-on-macos

Comment: I could not get a sample to work either, but I put what I tried above.  I'm going to send this in as a bug report